# CSS animation classes not working when applied with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

Based on some googling about how you can't animate hidden (`display:none`) elements, I have the following:

#### HTML element styled with tailwind utility classes

```
<div class="absolute z-10 hidden overflow-hidden md:hidden transform -translate-x-20 opacity-0 transition-all duration-500 delay-100 ease-out">
```

And this is a small fragment of the javascript that responds to open/close events on the related hamburger button:

```
    // on first open of the sidebar, this should remove the 'display: none'... 
    sidebar?.classList.toggle('hidden')

    // so now these should trigger animations:
    sidebar?.classList.toggle('opacity-0') // => 100% opacity, but without transition.
    sidebar?.classList.toggle('-translate-x-20') // => correct x-pos, but without transition.
```